# Android - Scrollbars on Custom ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been using the Android Masonry (http://code.google.com/p/android-masonry/) in my project. I noticed that after adding a lot of views that contain bitmaps I run out of memory. I think this is because the viewgroup keeps in memory all its child even when they are not being displayed in the screen. I was told that I needed to work on this code to make it more memory optmized by invalidating the views that were not in the screen.

The first thing I am trying to do with this code is removing the ScrollView that wraps the Masonry viewgroup, but what happens is that I dont get any scrollbars. Is there anything I can do in the Masonry.java to make the it scrollable when there is no ScrollView wrapping this componenent? Once I get the scrollbars working, I can start thinking on how to manage the views that should be recycled.

Thanks
T

Comment: You could try using 2 listviews, it works untill some point, but the method is flawed if the list sizes differ greatly.